# How do I use Camel File Component Consumer using multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

How do I use Camel File Component Consumer using multiple threads ?
meaning I have this code :

```
<route id="incomingFile">
                    <from
                           uri="file://{{incomingFileBaseFolder}}?filter=#fileFilter&amp;recursive=true&amp;readLock=changed&amp;move=${file:parent}/.backup/${date:now:yyyy}/backup_${exchangeId}_${file:onlyname.noext}.${file:name.ext}&amp;sortBy=file:modified&amp;delay={{incomingFileDelay}}" />
                    <transacted />
                    <threads poolSize="10">
                           <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
                           <setHeader headerName="{{incoming_file_backup_date_header_name}}">
                                 <simple>$simple{date:now:yyyy}
                                 </simple>
                           </setHeader>
                           <bean ref="saveFile" method="duplicateCeck" />
                           <to uri="direct:validateFileDirect" />
                           <to uri="direct:inputFileContentHandle" />
                    </threads>
             </route>
```

but it does not seems to work on more than one file at a time.
How do I make it happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<transacted/>` as it does not support asynchronous routing. Also transactions only works with component/resources that support JTA transactions natively, which typically is only JMS and JDBC.

Comment: Hi yes I need the transacted as I'm doing jpa persistence in my spring beans. So you are saying I can not use multi threading for the file consuming with transacted ?